# Button not centering after moving it to bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a form where the submit is always at the bottom and in the center.

I'm centering by using `text-align: center` in the parent div and moving it to the bottom with `position: absolute` and `bottom: 20px`, but it seems that after I do that it moves slightly off center - why is this case and how do I remedy this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <p>
      <input name='group 1' type='radio' id='1' />
      <label for='1'>option 1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name='group 1' type='radio' id='2' />
      <label for='2'>option 2</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name='group 2' type='radio' id='3' />
      <label for='3'>option 1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name='group 1' type='radio' id='4' />
      <label for='4'>option 1</label>
    </p>
    <button type='submit'>
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f9ktLn9o/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you've pulled it out of the stack using `position: absolute;` it'll now be centered to the left of the button. If you translate it 50% of the width of the button to the left, it should fix the issue.

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f9ktLn9o/4/

Comment: out of all the answers, like this one the best. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at *Computed* styles you will see `left` and `right` *position* values defined in the box model. 
You'll need to unset these values with your own, with a few other adjustments, you will achieve the intended behaviour.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9ktLn9o/6/)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  /* Additional */
  position: relative; /* position absolute child relative to parent */
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  /* Additional */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <p>
      <input name='group 1' type='radio' id='1' />
      <label for='1'>option 1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name='group 1' type='radio' id='2' />
      <label for='2'>option 2</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name='group 2' type='radio' id='3' />
      <label for='3'>option 1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name='group 1' type='radio' id='4' />
      <label for='4'>option 1</label>
    </p><button type='submit'>
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of your css:

```
button {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40%;
}
```

It work for chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE (just tested these)
By using `position: absolute;`, the button is fixed in the page, but not fixed in the div. 
Always try  to use percentage and not pixel if you can (responsive design is way beter for end users)